# accidentally deleted /var folder

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, mac

I accidentally moved my `/var` folder to trash and now unable to login to mac. The only solution I found until now it to recover OS X.

I have tried to move `/var` back to `/private` folder in single user mod, since it is Read-only and not allowing me to perform this action.

Is there any way I can move /var folder back without re-installing `OS X`. I am having `Mavericks` as OS.

Answer (score 2):

When in single user mode you must enter the command at the begininng to make it writeable.

```
/sbin/mount -uw /
```

Then move the /var folder back to /private

```
mv /Path/To/var /private/
```